# How to detect circular structures?

Tags: javascript

For example, this code:

```
var a = {};
a.a = a;
JSON.stringify(a);
```

Will throw:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

My question is, how to detect a circular structure?

Comment: What do you mean by "detecting"? In this it is pretty obvious since there is the same var before and after the `=`

Comment: gnur: He means, given an arbitrary data structure, determine if it's cyclic.

Comment: You can also take a look at the [answer I posted to similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15179204/592253) which gives an example and a link a jsfiddle where you can test it.

Comment: I came across this error using `express` in `node` where i did this for testing purposes:  `res.send(req)` or `res.json(req)`.  I was trying to send back the initial request as the response - I don't know enough about express to know why this was an invalid action or what a valid alternative would be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Crockford's [JSON implementation](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js) does just that.  It looks like it just keeps a list while traversing the object graph.  The code is fairly easy to follow.

Comment: I still cannot stand how Crockford left-aligns all comments in his code. I find it so hard to follow jumping left as I read the code top-down.

Comment: @RoatinMarth: on the contrary, it allows me to focus on the code when I read the code; and when I read the documentation, I don’t need to read the code.  Comments pertaining to the code itself are placed with the code itself.

Comment: Roatin: So paste it in your editor, select all, indent-region.  Why is this worth complaining about?  You could have fixed it faster than writing that comment.

Comment: @Ken that function is bullcrap. Try retrocycling the global object in NodeJS it'll get you a nice sweet range error (maximum call stack exceeded).

Answer (score 4):

Here is function using native JSON detection

```
function isCircular (d) {
  try {JSON.stringify(d)}
  catch (e) {return true}
  return false
}
```