# How to tell if a JavaScript variable is a reference to another variable

Tags: javascript

If I make an object, and then set another variable equal to that object, it's just a pointer to the original object. Is there a way to tell if a variable is just a reference, and if so, determine the original variable name?

E.g if I want to json encode an object that has a property that references back to the original object, it creates an infinite loop. I'd like to test if a property is a reference and if so just mark it as such, without rewriting the same object.

Comment: You can do something else, remember a list of objects you already encoded and then check each one before encoding them.
But doesn't `JSON.stringify` take care of what you want?

Comment: Related (if that's what you actually wanted, please edit your question so we can simply close it as a dupe): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582001/is-there-a-way-to-test-circular-reference-in-javascript

Comment: I was interested in the actual question, but one application was the example. I think your answer below addresses the question correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var foo = {'some': 'object'};
var bar = foo;
```

After this, `foo` and `bar` are **exactly the same** as in "they both point to the same object". But besides that there is no relationship between `foo` and `bar`, so `bar` is not a reference to `foo` but to the same object. So the answer is "no" since JavaScript does not have references to other variables.

However, to check for circular dependencies - which is what you actually need/want in your example - there are various other, more appropriate, solutions available this question: [Is there a way to test circular reference in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582001/is-there-a-way-to-test-circular-reference-in-javascript)

Additionally, native JSON encoding using `JSON.stringify()` already checks for this:

```
>>> var obj = {};
>>> obj.x = obj;
>>> JSON.stringify(foo)
TypeError: cyclic object value
```