# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON - find error in json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, contentful

I'm using Contentful with a MEAN stack. I query the Contentful API and get back a json object.

```
contentClient.entries(query, function(err, entries){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(entries);
});
```

I've just been receiving the following error:

`[TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON]`

The object is massive (over 3000 lines when I export it from the console to a document). So I can't post it here, but I am wondering if there is a way to find where the circular structure issue is within the object and how I remedy this?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582001/is-there-a-way-to-test-circular-reference-in-javascript

Comment: I'd be very interested if you could do: var util = require('util') and then console.log(util.inspect(entries)), and provide the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a developer at Contentful and I think I can help with the second part of your question.

As for the first part, greuze's answer is the ideal thing to do if you're in node land. An alternative (that can also be helpful in the browser) is using https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-json-stringify

As for the second part, a thing the contentful.js library does is resolve links to other entries. The raw JSON contains just an object with metadata for links, but the linked entries come in an attached includes property. The library then goes and resolves those so you don't have to do it yourself.

However, we do allow you to create circular links when linking entries to each other (and you can even link an entry to itself!) and right now we haven't implemented a good way to detect and present those in the CMS (although that's a nice feature idea that I'll propose).

So once you do find that Circular reference, that should be your root issue.

Answer (score 1):

In node 0.10 and 0.12, you can do:

```
var obj = {"child": {}};
obj.obj = obj;
util.inspect(obj, {depth: null})
```

and you will get something like:

```
'{ child: {}, obj: [Circular] }'
```

Depth indicates how many times to recurse while formatting the object (2 by default), null indicates indefinitely.

To find where are circular references, it is pretty easy to look for "[Circular]" in the resulting string.

Comment: Looking at the source, console.log defers to util.format() which defers to a mess of code to deal with deep object nesting, formatting, and util.inspect(). Prior to util existing as a package most of util existed within console.js. I tried messing around w/ console.log to see how I could even make [TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON] occur, but couldn't. Every time I did, I just saw the output of [Circular] as you outlined as the behaviour of util.inspect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a performant solution, but it works. We're getting this issue only when we render things on the server side using Next.js.

We have an articles model that requires related articles which end up being linked and so this crops up quite often.

Here's what I did to solve the problem:

```
let article = await contentful.getArticle({
  'fields.slug': query.slug,
  include: 2,
})

const circularRef = _.get(article, 'items[0].fields.relatedArticle.fields.relatedArticle')

if (circularRef) {
  delete article.items[0].fields.relatedArticle.fields.relatedArticle
}
```

Note that `getArticle` is a helper method I created and `get` is from the lodash library. Hope that helps.